# Building Latex/Tex arguments in lua

Tags: lua, latex, tex

I use lua to make some complex job to prepare arguments for macros in Tex/LaTex.

Part I
Here is a stupid minimal example :

```
\newcommand{\test}{\luaexec{tex.print("11,12")}}% aim to create 11,12
\def\compare#1,#2.{\ifthenelse{#1<#2}{less}{more}}
\string\compare11,12. : \compare11,12.\\ %answer is less
\string\test : \test\\ % answer is 11,12
\string\compare : \compare\test. % generate an error
```

The last line creates an error. Obviously, Tex did not detect the "," included in \test.

How can I do so that \test is understood as 11 followed by , followed by 12 and not the string 11,12 and finally used as a correctly formed argument for \compare ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several misunderstandings of how TeX works.

Your `\compare` macro wants to find something followed by a comma, then something followed by a period. However when you call

```
\compare\test
```

no comma is found, so TeX keeps looking for it until finding either the end of file or a `\par` (or a blank line as well). Note that TeX *never* expands macros when looking for the arguments to a macro.

You might do

```
\expandafter\compare\test.
```

provided that `\test` immediately expands to tokens in the required format, which however don't, because the expansion of `\test` is

```
\luaexec{tex.print("11,12")}
```

and the comma is hidden by the braces, so it doesn't count. But it wouldn't help nonetheless.

The problem is the same: when you do

```
\newcommand{\test}{\luaexec{tex.print("11,12")}}
```

the argument is *not* expanded. You might use “expanded definition” with `\edef`, but the problem is that `\luaexec` is not fully expandable.

If you do

```
\edef\test{\directlua{tex.sprint("11,12")}}
```

then

```
\expandafter\compare\test.
```

would work.

Comment: Thanks egreg for pointing out my two errors, I would sum up this way :
- since Tex don't expand when looking for arguments, I have to use \expandafter to have the desired expansion (here expansion of \test)
- since \luaexec isn't expandable, I need to use \directlua which is expandable

I guess edef is necessary to fully expand \test because \expandafter only expands once. To check I understand well, I could also use several \expandafter with just a normal \def, right ?

With these amendments, it works fine ! Thanks ! I will try to transfer this to the real case.

Comment: To pin out the difficulty: the misleading point is that \testA defined as \def\test{\directlua{tex.sprint("11,12")}} and \testB defined as \edef\test{\directlua{tex.sprint("11,12")}} give the same when using \testA and \testB out of a macro since they are indefinitely expanded. Within a macro, it's not the same since there is no expansion. When expanded with \expandafter, since there is only one expansion, the difference remains. The difference can be made visible by using \meaning\testA and \meaning\testB.

Comment: @user1771398 Yes, good analysis. The problem with `\expandafter` is that you must precisely know how many expansion steps you need. For instance, `\def\test{\directlua{...}}` needs two, but other constructions might need three or more.