# Building Latex/Tex arguments in lua (2)

Tags: lua, latex, tex, tikz

The same question as [Building Lates/Tex arguments in lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30025788/building-latex-tex-arguments-in-lua) with a more complex case :

Part II
A more adequate model :
I try to replace the plot arguments by a lua production:
Original:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\draw[smooth,samples=100,domain=-3.0:2.0] plot(\x,{(\x-1.0)^2.0*(\x+3.0)});
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

Replacement by a "manual" macro : works fine

```
\def\tempD{(\x-1)*(\x-1)*(\x+3)}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\draw[smooth,samples=100,domain=-3.0:2.0] plot(\x,{\tempD}); % works fine
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

Trials to use a string produced by lua to replace the manual macro : still to be found

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
%\draw[smooth,samples=100,domain=-3.0:2.0] plot(\x,{\strfunc??????}); % the correct \strfuncXX is still to be found !
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

Trials to find the correct `\strfuncXX`, taking account egreg's infos :

```
\def\strfuncA{\luaexec{tex.write("(\\x-1)*(\\x-1)*(\\x+3)")}} % fails in draw, probably because it is not expanded enough as an argument of draw
%\edef\strfuncAA{\luaexec{tex.write("(\\x-1)*(\\x-1)*(\\x+3)")}} % fails because \luaexec non expandable
\def\strfuncB{\directlua{tex.write("(\\x-1)*(\\x-1)*(\\x+3)")}} % fails because \directlua has a problem managing the "\\"
\def\strfuncC{\directlua{tex.write("(x-1)*(x-1)*(x+3)")}}
\edef\strfuncCC{\directlua{tex.write("(x-1)*(x-1)*(x+3)")}} % works fine ... except that we get an expression with xs instead of \xs
\def\strfuncD{\directlua{tex.write("(\string\ x-1)*(\string\ x-1)*(\string\ x+3)")}} % \strfuncD fails (why ?)
%\edef\strfuncDD{\directlua{tex.write("(\string\ x-1)*(\string\ x-1)*(\string\ x+3)")}} % \strfuncD fails so \edef will fail
```

Moving from `\luaexec` to `\luadirect` (or `\directlua`) created a problem with the compulsory `\x` I have to produce that I cannot solve.